# Is adding dynamic rows to a table in dart slow?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm adding 300 rows to a table dynamically and it's taking about 1.75 seconds to add the rows and at least another 1 to 1.5 seconds to render. I know this might sound like I am being picky but overall it's a 3+ second delay to show the table when this happens and the calcs behind that table execute really quickly.

I'm using a simple  TableRowElement row = tBody.addRow();
and then row.addCell() for about ten columns of data. The data is coming from a List of Map objects.

If this is normal, then is there a way I can get the rows to render as they are created to sort of "speed up" the process from the user's point of view?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with the built JS output? This is what matters in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have. It's twice as slow on my phone (Galaxy Note 4). In a previous non-core/paper version it was less than half the time. I guess I am not sure where best to focus my efforts in speeding this up. If you have any direction I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Did you ensure to build in release mode? A common way to speed this up is to only render what's actually visible like polymers core-list or bwu_datagrid and others do.

Comment: Thanks! I had not come across the datagrid yet and really appreciate that suggestion. I wanted to add sorting anyway so it looks like that might do the trick. The example had tens of thousands of rows and was very fast.